# Is there an equivalent, in Spanish, for the interrobang?

Tags: puntuación

In English, we have the interrobang -- ‽ (often represented by ?! or !?) -- which can express incredulity and surprise in-text. Does Spanish have an equivalent punctuation mark? If so, would it, like the exclamation point and question mark, require an antecedent at the beginning of a sentence?

Comment: And yes, I know this is in English. I've avoided asking questions on here in English so far, but this one was *too hard* to machine-translate!

Comment: I wouldn't say we have the interrobang even in English.  It's a [failed](http://www.shadycharacters.co.uk/2011/04/the-interrobang-part-1/) [experiment](http://www.shadycharacters.co.uk/2011/04/the-interrobang-part-2/).

Comment: Are you sure the interrobang is English? Maybe it's just like `?` and `!` and doesn't belong to any one language. In any case I've never seen it used other than when it's being talked about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/137/origin-of-and/151#151) provides a possible answer to this question as well:

> You can start with one sign (¡) and close with the other (?) if the meaning is mixed, but using both is preferred.
>
> *¡Que ha dicho qué?*
>
> *!¿Que ha dicho qué?!*

And according to [Wikipedia](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrobang), you can also use this form, although it is not considered standard:

> *⸘Que ha dicho qué‽*

Comment: According to wikipedia it exists even an "Inverted interrobang" called gnaborretni (interrobang written backwards), but I have never seen it in Spanish and it isn't mentioned by RAE (Real Academia Española, the official organisation). Anyway, the proposed solution by RAE is the first solution given by Filmzy instead of using both symbols at the beginning and at the end of the sentence.

Comment: Agree with Javi.  You should use an opening of one mark, and a closing of the other: ¿ … ! or ¡ … ?.  You should not double the marks in Spanish.

Answer (score 0):

Interrobang is non existent in spanish. Its usage is incorrect, as the symbols is not defined in the Ortografía.

Starting with one symbol and closing with the other is the only correct form. It is indiferent which one you use to open and which one to close (Ortografía, 3.4.9.2, b), page 393)