# Proper placement of inverted question mark

Tags: ortografía, puntuación

What is the proper placement of the inverted question mark in sentences that are not completely questions?  A common example:

> Hello, how are you?
>
> (¿)Hola, (¿)cómo estás?

Or:

> That's great, isn't it?
>
> (¿)Eso es maravilloso, (¿)verdad?

I believe I have seen both forms.  Is one preferred over the other? And if the latter form is preferred, how does this affect punctuation before the inverted question mark?  Should the previous phrase be turned into a stand-alone sentence with proper ending punctuation, or is it okay to use a comma? Likewise, should the second phrase be considered a separate sentence, and therefore capitalized?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Inverted question marks](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/137/origin-of-and/191#191)

Comment: @Joze: With your edit to the original question they may be duplicates... but I think the body of the question needs to be updated, too, not just the title.

Comment: I figured just copying the answer. I dunno if that is forbidden though. I guess they are different questions...

Comment: @Joze: I don't think it's forbidden... your answer may answer both questions, but the proper handling there is probably to mark this a duplicate (as you've already voted for).  And/or update your answer to more directly address this question when you post it here.

Comment: I really think the origin and usage of `¿` should be two separate questions though they're obviously related and are fine mentioning other. Otherwise we risk the TL;DR effect. All the usage subtleties belong here. All the reasoning behind belong on the "origin" question.

Comment: I want to say `¿` goes at the beginning of the clause which is the sentence, but I'm not sure enough how technically correct that is.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Spanish suggests the open question mark but modern Spanish doesn't enforce its use. Anyway, be careful where it goes. Using your examples, you could say:

> Hola, ¿cómo estás?

And also

> Eso es maravilloso, ¿verdad?

You don't use the open question mark at the beginning because the entire sentence is not a question, actually *Hola* (within a greeting) is an exclamation, so the proper (and strict) way is:

> ¡Hola! ¿Cómo estás?

So, answering your questions:

1. It's kind of 'well-written' if you use opening question marks. But it is not strictly necessary UNLESS you are writing legal documents (then it's a must).
2. Yes, it affects the punctuation. For this purpose you can just see the ¿ and ? as dots.
3. In examples like yours it's not strictly necessary to use a comma but it's recommended UNLESS you are ending previous sentence with exclamation (as within *¡Hola! ¿Cómo estás?*).
4. Considering the second phrase as separate sentence depends on the context, but take care of the capitalization. You capitalize only if it's considered as a separate sentence or if is preceded by an exclamation or another question mark.

> ¡Hola! ¿Cómo te ha ido?

Which translates as "Hi, how you doing?", and:

> Eso es correcto, ¿verdad?

Which translates as "That's true, right?". In this case, "right" is interpreted within the context and therefore doesn't get capitalized.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm sorry but it is enforced in official documents and articles. It is still important for the understanding of the phrase. It may be ignored talking to friends or SMS or messenger. But not while writing seriously.

Comment: Sure, I already wrote that on my answer - UNLESS you are writing legal documents (then its a must). -

Comment: I meant articles aswell, or a academic paper. Not really limited to legal documents. Anything that is outside of the informal must use them.

Comment: I would say use them when you're writing formal stuff, things you want to be treated seriously. If there's an expectation of writing correctly, us it. In informal chatty stuff you can be as lazy as you want, like leaving out capital letters and apostrophes and full stops in English.

Comment: Modern Spanish enforce the use of opening question and exclamation marks. Suppression of opening question marks is wrong. Even in informal chat is wrong. The rule is clear: "opening marks must not be suppressed."

Answer (score 7):

Both the `¿?` and `¡!` signs encapsulate statements that make an exclamation or a question or both. Both signs have the same rules.

In the usage of both it is very important to have the following considerations:

- They have to be used at the beginning and the end of the statement.
- It is mandatory in spanish to use them. It will not be ignored as in the spelling of other languages that use only the ending mark because they have other grammatical rules that help identify the beginning of the statement (question or exclamation)
  For example in spanish you can ask: `¿Estás comiendo en el restaurante?` and the equivalent in english would be `Are you eating at the restaurant?` in this case in english you have the word order that lets you know that it is a question. You can formulate exactly the same sentence in spanish `Estás comiendo en el restaurante.` that would have another meaning and tone.
- You never put a point at the end of the statement. The question or exclamation mark already delimits the end.

It was implemented in 1754 on the second edition of *Ortografía de la real academia* because there are many cases in which you can't tell if the statement is a question or not, even if the ending has a mark, you won't know where the question begins. For instance:

> Susana se fue de la casa muy tarde y después se fue a donde sus amigos por la noche?

In this case what is the question? did Susana left the house late? Did she go to her friends house? Did she go at night?

Possible Fix:

> Susana se fue de la casa muy tarde, después, ¿se fue a donde sus amigos por la noche?

There are other alternative fixes. But I'm too lazy to write them.

Nota: Please remember that is important to know that these are statements when inside a sentence, and sentences when on their own!!!
Examples:

Statement form:

> Susana, ¿has decidido qué vas a hacer?
> Pepe, ¡cuánto me alegro de que hayas venido!
> Si no responde, ¿qué le vamos a decir?

Sentence form:

> ¿Has decidido qué vas a hacer, Susana?
> ¡Cuánto me alegro de que hayas venido, Pepe!
> ¿Qué le vamos a decir si no responde?

There are other uses for the inverted question marks, for instance to express irony or doubt, but in those cases it is mandatory the use of parentheses.

Examples:

> José Pérez Segovia es el presidente (?) de la asociación.
>
> Tendría mucha gracia (?) que llegara a la cita con un día de retraso.

And exclamation marks to express surprise or irony:

> Un joven de treinta y seis años (!) fue el ganador del concurso de composición.
>
> Está más gordo que nunca, pero dice que sólo pesa ochenta kilos (!) en la báscula de su casa.

If someone finds better examples don't hesitate to edit the answer.

Addressing your specific questions:

There is no preference between the statement form and the sentence form. There must always be a comma before the Question in a statement form, or it will change the tone of the sentence. Contrary to what Randolf said. The comma is required if the question is in a statement form, you can read the sources for a more specific explanation.

It is okay to use the comma, but you can also make it a stand alone sentence. Like this:

> Eso es maravilloso. ¿Verdad?

Sources:

[Profesor en línea](http://www.profesorenlinea.cl/castellano/SignoInterrogExclam.htm)

[Uso de los signos de exclamación e interrogación](http://www.uamenlinea.uam.mx/materiales/lengua/puntuacion/html/inter.htm)

[Signos de puntuación](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signo_de_puntuaci%C3%B3n)

Comment: But the usage of both signs is relevant for the question, since both signs have the same rules.

Comment: Then I'd suggest explaining that in the preamble... "Both the ¿ and ¡ use the same rules..."  Because as written, it isn't immediately clear what "both signs" you're referring to in your opening sentence.

Comment: Edit done. And I addressed your specific questions at the end. :-)

Comment: I wouldn't choose the word "statement" because that's usually considered to be the opposite of a question. Statements end in full stops (periods). I want to suggest instead the words "phrase" or "clause" but I'm not 100% sure what is best.

Comment: Hmmm.... I don't know either... english is not my native language so that nuance is a bit foreign to me. Feel free to edit the question as you see fit. :-)

Comment: @hippietrail "sentence"?

Comment: @Alenanno: No "sentence" is definitely wrong because the notable quality of `¿` and `¡` is that they can and do often occur in the middle of a sentence.

Comment: @hippietrail Oh wait, I confused the terms for a moment! Under "sentence", there is "clause". "Phrase" is even smaller in this classification.

Comment: Yes I think without looking it up that a clause is a specific subunit of a sentence that contains a verb. In fact a simple sentence will have just one clause. A phrase on the other hand is any arbitrary span of words, they don't necessarily form any special kind of unit. "And the" is still a phrase but it's not any special kind of phrase. One pitfall is that "frase" in Spanish means "sentence" in English but is cognate with "phrase" in English. \-:

Answer (score -2):

The proper use of the inverted question mark is always at the beginning of the sentence. The example you provided would actually be : Hola! ¿Como esta? It would be considered two separate sentences as "Hola" is traditional greeting and therefore makes a statement, Como esta? is the actual question.

The inversion also holds true in the placement of the exclamation point as well, one inverted at the beginning of the sentence & one at the end.

Comment: Not necessary roman. "Cómo estás" introduce the subject so it's unnecessary the use of "ousted". Also, the contraction "Ud." Isn't that common. Actually the use of "usted" or "tu" is prevalent.