# Is it acceptable to leave out the inverted punctuation marks?

Tags: ortografía, puntuación

Is it acceptable to leave out inverted question marks and exclamation points (¿ ¡) from questions and exclamatory sentences?

I ask this because some computers and other devices I use won't let me add an input method that supports inverted punctuation marks.

Comment: See this [Question](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/137/origin-and-usage-of-and/191#191) to learn about usage and origin.

Comment: You could consider the use of a spell checker.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Officially (according to the Real Academia Española), both must be used in almost all cases. The [Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/) includes a [section on question marks and exclamation points](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?origen=RAE&lema=interrogaci%F3n%20y%20exclamaci%F3n%20(signos%20de)), which says:

> Son signos dobles, pues existe un signo de apertura y otro de cierre, que deben colocarse de forma obligatoria al comienzo y al final del enunciado correspondiente; no obstante, existen casos en los que solo se usan los signos de cierre (→ 3a y d).
>
> 3a) Los signos de cierre escritos entre paréntesis se utilizan para expresar duda (los de interrogación) o sorpresa (los de exclamación), no exentas, en la mayoría de los casos, de ironía: Tendría gracia (?) que hubiera perdido las llaves; Ha terminado los estudios con treinta años y está tan orgulloso (!).
>
> 3d) Es frecuente el uso de los signos de interrogación en la indicación de fechas dudosas, especialmente en obras de carácter enciclopédico. Se recomienda colocar ambos signos, el de apertura y el de cierre: Hernández, Gregorio (¿1576?-1636), aunque también es posible escribir únicamente el de cierre: Hernández, Gregorio (1576?-1636).

In other words, they are considered paired signs, and should always be placed both at the beginning and end, except in a couple special cases where only the closing sign is used. Those special cases include:

- A single question mark or exclamation point in parentheses used to express doubt, surprise, or irony.
- Question marks used to indicate that a date is unsure. In this case it's still recommended to use opening and closing question marks, but a single closing mark is accepted as well.

However, as with most areas of grammar, the official rule isn't what is practically found in all Spanish-speaking areas at all times. In informal Spanish--for example, chatting online--it's common for people to drop the inverted signs or accents on vowels likely because of the point you mentioned (it can take some effort to set up a computer to type them easily). But in written, formal Spanish, the rule is generally followed.

In terms of the practical question of typing special characters on a keyboard, see [this meta question](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10/easy-way-to-type-accented-characters) which lists some options. I can't imagine there are many devices that are *impossible* to configure to type special characters.

Comment: Very well documented answer