# Estás enfermo - should it be enfermas

Tags: vocabulario, verbos

I don't quite follow the following:

> Are you ill? - Estás enfermo *(from google translate so this could be wrong)*

So the verb "to be ill" is *"enfermar"*. So not sure where *"enfermo"* is coming from? My understanding is that *"enfermo"* is the first person present conjugation.

Is this a suffix thing or a verb turning into an adjective etc.?

Comment: Enfermar means "to sicken"  (or "to make ill").  That isn't the same thing as to be ill.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Google translation is literal and correct in this case: *enfermo* is an adjective that means "ill, sick, diseased". Since Google cannot guess number or gender from the English sentence, this could also be translated with *enfermos* (plural masculine), *enferma* (singular feminine), or *enfermas* (plural feminine).

It happens that *enfermo* is also the first person singular, present tense, indicative mood, of the verb *enfermar*. This verb is usually pronominal, i.e. it takes a personal pronoun that looks like a reflexive. In any case *enfermar* doesn't mean "to be ill", but "to become ill" or "to make (somebody) ill". This is **not** what you see in the sentence *¿Estás enfermo?* - that is clearly the adjective.

Answer (score 5):

> So the verb "to be ill" is *"enfermar"*

Actually "to be ill" is not a verb. Only "to be" is the verb; "ill" is an adjective, or a qualifier. You ask *"Are you ill?"* just like you could ask *"Are you tired?"*, *"Are you blonde?"* or *"Are you Belgian?"*.

With that in mind, *enfermo* (or *enferma* in feminine) is just the Spanish adjective for "ill":

> **[enfermo, ma](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=FHIHrUc)**.
>   Del lat. *infirmus*.
>
> 1. adj. Que padece enfermedad. U. t. c. s.

So with *estás* being second person singular of *estar*, "to be"; and *enfermo* being "ill", the correct translation is indeed:

> *¿Estás enfermo?*

(Your quoted translation is missing the question marks, but [you must always include them](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/922/13628)).

You're right about *"enfermo"* (also) being one of the conjugations of the verb *"enfermar"*, but that verb means "to become ill". It is not used to say that you *are* ill.

Answer (score 1):

> Are you ill? - ¿Estás enfermo?

As others have explained, "enfermo" is an adjective here.

Since Spanish requires that adjectives match gender, and show an S for a plural subject, if you ask two women this question, then yes, you will need "enfermas":

> Are you [two ladies] ill? - ¿Están enfermas?

Note, *enfermar* does exist as a verb.  For example:

> Quiero acostarme temprano hoy.  Creo que me estoy enfermando.

This means

> I want to go to bed early tonight.  I think I'm getting sick (coming down with something).